# Pandas shifted index column

Tags: python, pandas

I got a filtered pandas dataframe and I would like create a new column that is based on the shifted index value.

|  | Point |
| --- | --- |
| 124 | 12 |
| 559 | 1 |
| 717 | 12 |

Goal:

|  | Point | Pre_Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 12 | 559 |
| 559 | 1 | 717 |
| 717 | 12 | NaN |

How could I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data['index'] = data.index
data['Pre_Index'] = data['index'].shift(-1)
```

Comment: I didn't know I need an extra step to get this work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `Series.shift(-1)`

```py
df['Pre_Index'] = df['Index'].shift(-1)
# or
df['Pre_Index'] = df.index.shift(-1)
```

Comment: Sorry the Index is not actual column. It is the index column which the value could be obtained by df.index